# loading CSS with jQuery not applying styles to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a CSS file dynamically after the `document.ready` function fired. This is what I have:

```
$.get(TheCSSTag.href, function () {

    alert('loaded');
    DoSomething();

}, "text/css");
```

The problem is that the alert triggers fine (which I assume means the CSS loaded) but the styles aren't applied to the HTML elements.

Note: other solutions that involve creating a CSS tag and appending to the DOM like this `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(TheCSSTag);` don't work for me because I need a callback function to execute when the CSS file loaded.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that shows the CSS is being added to the document, or does `$.get()` do that if you add `"text/css"` there?

Comment: Loading CSS file dynamically is usually a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia: the css is loaded from the client based on the screen resolution.

Comment: @frenchie: Did you considered [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)?

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia: no, the name of the CSS is determined at runtime. Media queries won't work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is... You're not actually telling the browser to use the CSS. You're just asking jQuery to get it for you. Inside the callback of `$.get`, you need to actually inject it into your page.

Here's an example using jQuery where you read the entire thing and put it into a `style` tag inside `head`:

```
$.when($.get('your_css_file.css')).done(function (response) {
    $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'))
})
```

Another way would be to simply add the URL to the head:

```
$('<link /')
    .attr('type', 'text/css')
    .attr('rel', 'stylesheet')
    .attr('href', 'your_css_file.css')
    .appendTo($('head'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the CSS file to the page. `$.get()` won't do that for you.

```
$.get(TheCSSTag.href, function(){

     $('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':TheCSSTag.href}).appendTo('head');
     alert('loaded');
     DoSomething();

}, "text/css");
```

**Please note: without xdomain permissions $.get will only load local files** though you can just add them to head without using $.get first.